# Google apps script find the number of items on a form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there a way to get a count of items listed on a google form. For instance I create a google sign-up form for a class my form would look something like below.

```
function getFormItemCnt(){
 var f = FormApp.openById('abcd123kfeofkl-mdsfsd8rferSAFRgdsl')
 var formRs = f.getResponses();
 var fR = fRs[formRs.length-1];
 var iRs = fR.getItemResponses();

   for (var j = 0; j < iRs.length; j++) {
     var iR = iRs[j]; 
     // Is there a way to get the doing something like below
     // var cnt = iR.getItem().getCount();
}
```

Comment: You could use getItems which gives you  an array of all items and the loop through all of the items (It's an array) getting each item type and count the types you wish to count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a dialog with the items index and type.

```
function myForm()
{
  var myForm=FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var items=myForm.getItems();
  for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
  {
    Logger.log('Item[%s].getItemType=%s',i,items[i].getType());
  }
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(Logger.getLog());
  FormApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Items');
}
```